# linux write all execute command info into a file

Tags: linux, shell

I know that **set -x** enables a mode of the shell where all executed commands are printed to the terminal.  But how can I write all those info to a certain file.
Not add the redirector operation one by one like **echo sth >> fileName**

Answer (score 0):

`set -x` outputs the information to stderr. You can redirect it to another file.

```
$ ./script.sh 2>./path/to/script.log
```

Comment: I can't directly invoke script.sh, it's called by another system. Is that possible I can achieve it by add some code in script.sh?

Comment: `exec 2>/./path/to/script.log`

Answer (score 0):

You can start a "script" environment by running `script file.txt` where file.txt is the file name that you can specify. This will save all your stdin and stdout commands to the file until you exit. Once done you can simply run `exit` on your terminal and the file will be saved.
For example:

`script file.txt`

`echo "Test command"`

`exit`

One problem with this approach is that all control characters will also be written to the file. If you want to remove these from your file, you can check this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output

Comment: I can't directly invoke script.sh, it's called by another system. Is that possible I can achieve it by add some code in script.sh?